# Curl : Not showing my header in log

Tags: curl

I'am trying to debug an outgoing GET HTTP request in my command line using curl.

```
curl --header "Authorization: Basic AAABBBCCCCDDDEEFFF=" https://myserver:8443/user?id=9829878 -vvv
```

The output log doesn't show my "Authorization" header previously set:

```
*   Trying 10.30.215.211...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to (nil) (10.30.215.211) port 3128 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to myserver:8443
> CONNECT myserver:8443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: myserver:8443
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
< Server: squid/3.1.23
< Mime-Version: 1.0
< Date: Mon, 09 Apr 2018 19:16:00 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 3207
< X-Squid-Error: ERR_ACCESS_DENIED 0
< Vary: Accept-Language
< Content-Language: en
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT
```

Is there any mistake in my curl request to set my header content ?

Comment: I don't think it's even reaching the point of making the GET. Your squid proxy seems to be refusing the connection itself.

Comment: How can know if the Authorization header has been successfully added to the request ?

Comment: It certainly would be added. But if you want to be 100% sure try connecting to a server which your proxy does allow. Maybe google.com or something. Curl's behavior isn't going to vary for different servers, so if it sends the header for google, it will do so for your server too. It might be your proxy which is stripping off the header before it reaches the end server, rather than curl.

Answer (score 0):

first curl try to establish a connection to the proxy, but fails, thus it never gets to send the `--header` headers. if you want to send the header to the proxy, instead of the target, use `--proxy-header` instead of `--header`. if you want to send the header to both, use both `--proxy-header` and `-header`.